# delete all occurences of a term in a list

Tags: prolog

> I know this sounds "duplicate" but please help me out

I have defined three terms as follows:

```
type([a, b, c, d]:location).
type([coffee, tea, lemonade, water, biscuits]: object).    
type([order(object, location)]: order).
```

I have a piece of code that then generates a list of random orders.

I now need a predicate that deletes all the terms that unify with `order(X, a)`, that is, deletes all the orders that have `a` as `location` from that list.
For instance, this is an example of list (printed this way to make it readable):

```
order(tea,a)
order(tea,b)
order(coffee,b)
order(water,c)
order(lemonade,d)
order(biscuits,a)
order(water,c)
order(tea,c)
order(coffee,d)
order(water,d)
```

applying such needed predicate `my_delete(List, [order(_, a), order(_, b)], Result)` would give:

```
order(water,c)
order(lemonade,d)
order(water,c)
order(tea,c)
order(coffee,d)
order(water,d)
```

---

So far I've tried to remove a sublist from the main list, but what it does is just delete a single element for `a` and a single element for `b`, not all of them. This is the code for such predicate (thanks also to this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239457/how-to-remove-a-list-from-a-list-in-prolog)):

```
remove_list([], _, []).
remove_list([X|Tail], L2, Result):-
    member(X, L2),
    !,
    remove_list(Tail, L2, Result). 
remove_list([X|Tail], L2, [X|Result]):-
    remove_list(Tail, L2, Result).
```

and a query that I tried, but didn't work as expected, was:

```
remove_list(Input_list, [ordine(_, a), ordine(_, b)], Result).
```

Notice that **I need duplicates**, so using sets won't work.

Comment: Does your Prolog dialect have an `exclude/3` predicate?

Comment: yes it does! how would I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negation `\+` to avoid further unification over recursion of your filter list:

```
remove_list([], _, []).
remove_list([X|Tail], ToDelete, Result):-
  (\+( memberchk(X, ToDelete) ) ->
    Result=[X|NResult] ;
    Result=NResult
  ),
remove_list(Tail, ToDelete, NResult).
```

Comment: gotta say, I've never seen such negation, neither the arrow ' -> ' .

Comment: The arrow is really bizarre stuff: [if then else](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) but the negation is important: [not provable](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%2B)/1) see also: [Keith L. Clark, "Negation as Failure", 1978](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~klc/neg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using `exclude/3`, which takes a predicate, input list and output list:

```
rev_memberchk(List, Member) :-
    memberchk(Member, List).

my_delete(Input_List, Orders, Result) :-
    exclude(rev_memberchk(Orders), Input_List, Result).
```

Using `memberchk/1` rather than `member/2` for efficiency; you don't need the bound output, just to know if it can unify. If you also have lambda expressions, this can be turned into a one-liner by removing the need to write a predicate with re-ordered arguments:

```
my_delete(Input_List, Orders, Result) :-
    exclude({Orders}/[X]>>memberchk(X, Orders), Input_List, Result).
```